# CSS transform Scale Hover Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, hover, transform

I am using CSS transform:scale(2.0); to animate the dots within a diagram. The effect works as intended in Safari, but in Chrome and apparently IE the dots are being clipped on hover.

This doesnt happen in a blank HTML document, just within this diagram, does anyone know a solution? or failing that a decent jQuery substitute.

The dots are positioned absolutely within the diagram

the development is at www.craigscott.net/succeed

thanks

General Map Link Styles

```
.link-box {width:20px; height:20px; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; background-color:  white; border-radius: 50%; 
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease; -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease; }


.link-box:hover { -webkit-transform:scale(2.0); 

-moz-transform:scale(2.0);
-o-transform:scale(2.0);
transform:scale(2.0);

transform-origin:50% 50%;

-ms-transform-origin:50% 50%; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; /* Firefox */
-o-transform-origin:50% 50%; /* Opera */

}
```

All the dots positions

```
.mobile-link {bottom:100px; right:135px;}
.mobile-link:hover {bottom:100px; right:135px;}
.visualization-link {bottom:270px; right:70px;}
.UEANDE-link {bottom: 165px; right:45px;}
.support-link {top:110px; left:170px;}
.tech-support-link {top:50px; left:265px;}
.data-govern-link {top:108px; right:175px;}
.payroll-link {left:135px; bottom:98px;}
.CRM-link {left:48px; bottom:165px;}
.HCMC-link {left:70px; top:252px;}
.semantic-link {right:82px; top:200px;}
.op-mod-link {right:30px; top:217px;}
.gameification-link {right:25px; top:270px;}
.jquery-link {right:85px; bottom:85px;}
.portal-link {right:40px; bottom:115px;}
.dashboard-link {right:0px; bottom:148px;}
.alerts-link {right:10px; bottom:200px;}
.support-pack-link {left:175px; top:57px;}
.psoft-link {left:128px; top:82px;}
.upgrades-link {left:130px; top:138px;}
.tech-services-link {left:220px; top:28px;}
.integration-link {left:265px; top:0px;}
.saas-link {left:310px; top:28px;}
.mdm-link {right:130px; top:83px;}
.data-quality-link {right:177px; top:60px;}
.screening-link {right:132px; top:136px;}
.PSGP-link {left:85px; bottom:82px;}
.RTI-link {left:125px; bottom:47px;}
.PAE-link {left:175px; bottom:67px;}
.CX-link {left:0px; bottom:147px;}
.HR-Help-link {left:10px; top:323px;}
.Event-link {left:62px; top:302px;}
.dynamic-link {left:22px; top:270px;}

.fusion-link {left:30px; top:220px;}
.PSHCM-link {left:80px; top:205px;}
```

Comment: Please post code examples instead of the website... Check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I just find an easy way , remove all transform:scale headache 
and write this

```
.link-box-child:hover {
   width:40px;
   height:40px;
   margin:-10px;
   position:absolute;
   padding:0px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a jQuery CSS3 effects framework like **[jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)** to handle your scaling/transformations.

Moreover, it handles your cross-browser issues for you. IMHO, it keeps things more organized and easier to maintain. It looks like what you are doing is cool, but might get out of hand quickly if you are not careful.

**Example:**

```
$(".box").hover( function () {

    $('.box').transition({ scale: 2.0 });
    $('.box').transition({ x: '40px' });
}, function () {
    $('.box').transition({ scale: 1.0 });
    $('.box').transition({ x: '-40px' });
});
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GJJp4/1/)

I know this isn't an exact solution to your problem, but you may find it easier to go this route if you stick to a solid framework to handle the messiness of CSS3 animations/effects.

Edit: Updated Fiddle to be more like your example tree "dot":

[JS Fiddle Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/GJJp4/8/)

**Javascript:**

```
$(".link-box").hover( function () {

    $('.link-box').transition({ scale: 2.0, x: '-40%' }, 'fast');
}, function () {
    $('.link-box').transition({ scale: 1.0, x: '0px' }, 'fast');
});
```